# How to combine / merge two StringCollection into one in C#

Tags: c#, linq, stringcollection

> How to combine / merge two StringCollection in C#

```
var collection1 = new StringCollection () { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
var collection2 = new StringCollection () { "DD", "EE", "FF" };
var resultCollection = collection1 + collection2 ; // TODO
```

Comment: StringCollection is an obsolete type, you shouldn't be using it *at all*.

Comment: I would agree that just about any generic collection like List<string> would be better, and I had never heard of StringCollection before, but if it's an obsolete type why would it still be supported in .NET 5.0RC1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection?view=netcore-3.1 Is it being kept around just to support legacy code? Maybe Mark is working on legacy code and needs to continue using StringCollection.

Comment: @TJRockefeller If you work on the .NET world, you should know that all code is made retrocompatible all the way to .NET 1.0. So it is still going to exist as long as Microsoft doesn't reverse that decision and finally obsolete so much **** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want a string collection you can just use `AddRange`

```cs
var collection1 = new StringCollection () { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
var collection2 = new StringCollection () { "DD", "EE", "FF" };
var resultCollection = new StringCollection();
resultCollection.AddRange(collection1.Cast<string>.ToArray());
resultCollection.AddRange(collection2.Cast<string>.ToArray());
```

Seems odd that `StringCollection` doesn't have any direct support for adding other `StringCollection`s. If efficiency is a concern, [Beingnin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357514/4708150) is probably more efficient than the answer here, and if you still need it in a `StringCollection` you can take the array that is generated and use `AddRange` to add that array of strings to a new `StringCollection`

Comment: "is probably more efficient" -> it is definitively more efficient. It's one loop over each collection versus two loops in your answer. Also, why not just call `AddRange` on one of the existing collections?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's not clear what the intent is for the string collections here. If you call `AddRange` on an existing collection it will modify that collection instead of giving you a new collection. The question does not suggest that it would be okay to mutate one of the original collections, so this combines the two collections into a new collection without changing the original collections.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy all to an array like this

```
    var collection1 = new StringCollection() { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
    var collection2 = new StringCollection() { "DD", "EE", "FF" };

    var array = new string[collection2.Count + collection1.Count];

    collection1.CopyTo(array, 0);
    collection2.CopyTo(array, collection1.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can cast as array and use [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netcore-3.1), please note this will also remove duplicates

```
var resultCollection = collection1.Cast<string>().Union(collection2.Cast<string>())
```

Comment: I think the collection variables need to be cast.

Comment: No there is no 'Union' extension for it.

Comment: @MarkMacneilBikeio `var resultCollection = collection1.Cast<string>().Union(collection2.Cast<string>());`

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for noticing it, updated my answer

Comment: Working fine now after casting. But why do we need cast explicitly to string again when its not necessary (Microsoft needs to avoid extra casting)

Comment: You need to cast because `StringCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @madreflection Oh Okay

Answer (score -2):

you can occupy List instead of StringCollection ...

```
        var collection1 = new List<string>() { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
        var collection2 = new List<string>() { "DD", "EE", "FF" };
        var resultCollection = collection1.Concat(collection2).ToList();
```

Comment: why use "object"?